# Is it possible for a routed component to have inputs?

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

Let's say we have this component:

```
class MyComp {
  @Input() name!: string;
  constructor(){}
}
```

And this route definition:

```
{ path: 'path', component: MyComp }
```

How can I provide the name input to MyComp instance ?

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18967

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pass data to routed component you can do it through route custom data:

```
{ path: 'path', component: MyComp, data: {name: 'myName'}}
```

Then retreive it from `ActivatedRoute`

```
constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe(data => {
      this.name=data.name;
  })
}
```